# Solutions for an equation

Tags: functions, roots

Consider an equation $$|x^2-|x|-2|=m.$$

For what values of $m$ does the above equation has exactly $6$ solutions?

My try:

I plotted the graph and found out that $m \in (2,2.25]$ fulfills the requirement. Any other solution without the involvement of graphs?

Comment: Maybe use a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $x^2=|x|^2$. Second, $$||x|^2-|x|-2|=m \implies |x|^2-|x|-2 = \pm m \implies |x|^2-|x|+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{9}{4}\pm m.$$
Consequently,
$$|x^2-|x|-2|=m \implies \left(|x|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{9}{4}\pm m.\tag 1$$
When $m > 9/4$ then $\left(|x|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \neq \frac{9}{4}- m$. As such, $(1)$ cannot have more than $4$ solutions.

When $0 < m < 9/4$, $(1)$ permits the following solutions:
$$|x| = \frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+m},\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+m}},\frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-m},\color{green}{\frac{1}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-m}}.$$
Among the above solutions, the red one is always negative. Therefore, $|x| \neq \frac{1}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}+m}$. The black ones are always positive. So we have at least four solutions ($|x|=a$ has two solutions: $x = \pm a$). The green one can be negative, zero or positive. In order to get six valid solutions, the green solution should be positive. That is,
$$\frac{1}{2}- \sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-m} > 0 \implies \frac{1}{4} > \frac{9}{4}-m \implies m > 2.$$
Consequently, the given equation has six solutions if
$$x \in \left(2,\frac{9}{4}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're talking about real solutions.

Separate into cases depending on sign of $x$ and then depending on sign of $x^2 - |x| - 2$.  In each case, your left side is a quadratic on a certain interval.
What does the quadratic do on each interval?  Increase, decrease, ...?